# Get Share Account privileged account entities in CRM sdk

Tags: c#, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have been wondering that how we could query to get list of Accounts which is Shared for a user. By using SDK I have tried the following methods but could not able to find out the proper solution:

```
 QueryExpression query1 = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "account",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "address1_city")

        };
 query1.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("account", "systemuser", "ownerid", "systemuserid", JoinOperator.Inner));
 query1.LinkEntities[0].Columns.AddColumns("fullname");
 query1.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "share";
```

I am new to CRM sdk working my head around this the whole day.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessRequest`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrievesharedprincipalsandaccessrequest.aspx).

```
var accessRequest = new RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessRequest
{
    Target = leadReference
};

// The RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessResponse returns an entity reference
// that has a LogicalName of "user" when returning access information for a
// "team."
var accessResponse = (RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccessResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(accessRequest);
Console.WriteLine("The following have the specified granted access to the lead.");
foreach (var principalAccess in accessResponse.PrincipalAccesses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}:\r\n\t\t{1}", GetEntityReferenceString(principalAccess.Principal), principalAccess.AccessMask);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and but this code if for getting the user id list for a account , when i gave system user as target it shows 'The 'RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccess' method does not support entities of type 'systemuser' . Actually I want the list of accounts which is shared to a particular accounts .

Comment: You cant share an account to an account.

Comment: Sorry  I was asking get the list of accounts which are shared to a particular systemuser . Please ignore the previous comment